# difference between colouring number and chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I would like to understand the difference between the chromatic number and the colouring number. I get definition of both but it seems to me that they will have the same values for any graph.

Def:

1. The chromatic number is the minimal number of colours necessary to colour a graph such that no two vertices of the same colour are adjacent
2. The colouring number of $G$ is $$\underset{L}{\text{min}} \underset{v\in V(G)}{\text{max}} \#\text{ left neighbours of $v$ in $L$} + 1$$ where $L$ is an ordering of the vertices

Suppose a graph $G$ has a chromatic number $k$ then it seems that you can always order the vertices such that the greedy algorithm will exactly give you a $k$-colouring. therefore the colouring number will also be exactly $k$

Comment: What is the chromatic number of $K_{n,n}$? What is the colouring number of $K_{n,n}$? (Hint: no matter how you order the vertices, some vertex will come last.) Yes, you can always order the vertices so that the greedy algorithm gives you an optimal colouring. If you know the colouring, list all the vertices of colour $1$ first, all the vertices of colour $2$ next, and so on. What's your point? How do you get to "therefore"?

Comment: $K_{n,n}$ has $2$ as chromatic number and by ordering them in a correct way, the greedy algorithm will give me a colouring with $2$ colours. (I think so anyway). I edited my question for it to be a bit clearer.

Comment: What is your definition of the colouring number? Maybe it would help if you edited that into your definition. According to the definition I'm familiar with, the colouring number of $K_{n,n}$ is $n+1.$ Yes, you can order the vertices of $K_{n,n}$ so that the greedy algorithm uses just two colours. Yes, every graph can be ordered so that the greedy algorithm produces an optimal colouring, so what?

Comment: If a graph $G$ has colouring number $k$ then $G$ is $k$-*choosable*, a.k.a. $k$-*list-colourable*. The graph $K_{3,3}$ is 2-colourable but it is not $2$-choosable.

Comment: What makes you think that, if you cn order the vertices of $G$ so that the greedy algorithm gives you a $k$-colouring, then the colouring number of $G$ is at most $k$?

Comment: Good, I like your definition. Now please apply it to the graph $K_{2,2}=C_4.$

Comment: I think you'll find that, no matter how you order the vertices of $C_4,$ the ***last*** vertex will have $2$ left neighbours, and so the colouring number is $3,$ while the chromatic number of course is $2.$

Comment: Exercise: The colouring number of an $n$-regular graph is $n+1.$

Comment: You never explained the "therefore" in the last paragraph of your question. I thought maybe your definition of "colouring number" was going to say something about greedy algorithms but it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed... Actually I hadn't understood the definition correctly. I understood it as the minimal number of colours that you could get using the greedy algorithm. but not true at all... What is the "colour" interpretation of this definition?

Comment: For one thing there's an implication: if you can order the vertices so that each vertex has $\lt k$ left neighbours, it follows (by the greedy algorithm!) that the graph is $k$-colourable. And you get the stronger result that it's $k$-choosable, if you know what that means.

Comment: ok I get that thanks